# What are the error scenarios handled by ErrorHandler in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I assume that all the throw statements in Angular 2 code are caught by ErrorHandler class in Angular 2 defined in error-handler.js.

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. Is there any other class for ErrorHandling?
3. Are there any scenarios that are not handled by ErrorHandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ErrorHandler-class.html) for ErrorHandler, you are kind of right.

The default implementation is indeed intercepting error and writing them in the console, they are no other class on the Angular 2 source but you can totally create it and implement it in your configuration.

The error thrown by SystemJS or any other component not directly used in Angular 2 are not handled by this ErrorHandler.